# Как переделать апдейт типа Message в json

Tags: python, aiogram

В тг-боте реализую игру в кости. Если распечатать переменную dice, то получим апдейт типа Message. Извлечь данные по принципу "ключ-значение" не получится. Но мне известно, что апдейт можно переделать в json, испробовал многие способы такой переделки, но не выходит. На скриншоте я поместил в метод json() пару "ключ-значение", знаю, что плохая затея. Это больше для примера.

```
@router.callback_query(Text(text=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']))
async def process_dice_but_press(callback: CallbackQuery, bot: Bot):
    await callback.message.edit_text(f'Вы выбрали - {callback.data}')
    dice = await bot.send_dice(callback.from_user.id)
    dice_value = dice.json(['dice']['value'])
    await sleep(4)
    if callback.data == str(dice_value):
        await callback.message.edit_text('Поздравляю, ты выиграл!')
    else:
        await callback.message.edit_text('Увы, но ты проиграл')
```

Comment: `router` в вашем случае это `Dispatcher`?

Comment: можете ли вы дополнить код, выведя его в минимально воспроизводимый пример?

Comment: Изучил ваш пример, вообще не вижу необходимости получать значение в виде json, если его можно вызвать вот так: `dice_value = dice.dice.value` P.S. да, выглядит так себе, странное ваше это dice.dice...